# Android 6.0+ не сохраняет изображения

Tags: java, android

Проблема такая, на версиях андройд меньше 6.0 все отлично работает, но на 6.0 и выше камера включается по нажатию кнопки, делается снимок. Но не создается директория и соответственно нет фото в нем

```
private void saveFullImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            File file = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + "photo_"
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            mOutputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutputFileUri);

        }
    }
    else {
        File file = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + "photo_"
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        mOutputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutputFileUri);
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAM_REQUEST);



}
private void createDirectory (){

    directory = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "MyApp");
    if (!directory.exists())
        directory.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` разве уже имеет знак / в конце?

Comment: Там же есть запрос)

Comment: Лучше перевести заголовок вопроса на русский.

Comment: На момент вызова `createDirectory()` у Вас `Permission is granted`?